# Laravel using calcuation during eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to query all products whose net price is less than a certain amount.
In my table i am storing only gross price and discount where netprice is the difference between gross price and discount

IN my table i have the following columns

products table

```
name,
gross_price,
discount_amount
```

So in my query i would like to get all items whose `gross_price - discount_amount` is less that a certain amount like 100

SO currently am using eloquent like

```
Product::where('', '<', 100) //stuck on how to add new net_price in the query
```

Am stuck on how i can add the calculation to my query. How do i add the calculation without needing to add another field to the table?

Comment: try Product::whereRaw('(gross_price - discount_amount)<100') ->get();

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ---

```
Product::where(\DB::raw('(gross_price - discount_amount)'),'<',100);
```

Hope it will help  you.